# Jquery animateText Not Working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying some jquery out and it isn't working as expected.

What is in the ul:li should explode, via the jquery script.

```
</div>
<div class="james">
    <ul id="example">
        <li>James Winfield</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="und">
    <p>Underground House DJ</p>
    <ul id="example">
        <li>Kaboom!</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#example").animateText([{
        offset: 0,
        duration: 20,
        animation: "explode"
    }]);
</script>
```

If I remove the James Winfield ul:li then the Kaboom! works - but not the other way around.

Can anyone help?

My page is http://www.jameswinfield.co.uk/v2.html#, and the instructions for the plugin are http://lukeas14.github.io/animateText.js/

Thanks
James

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Learn the basics: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have to use class when you want to target more than one element at once, IDs must be unique, do as follows instead:

```
</div>
    <div class="james">
       <ul class="example"><li>James Winfield</li></ul>
    </div>

    <div class="und">
        <p>Underground House DJ</p>
        <ul class="example"><li>Kaboom!</li></ul>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".example").animateText([
            {
                offset: 0,
                duration: 20,
                animation: "explode"
            }
    ]);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - however the James Winfield part still isn't working?